# Animation not working on UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview, uianimation

I have a UIImageView added as a subview. I am trying to animate it using transform. The animation doesn't, however the imageview is Scaled properly, it's just not auto reversing. Am I doing something wrong?

```
UIImageView * iv_tap = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gesture_tap"]];
    iv_tap.center = point;
    iv_tap.tag = 779;
    iv_tap.hidden = true;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                          delay:.05
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         iv_tap.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.8, 1.8);
                     }
                     completion:NULL];


    [self addSubview:iv_tap];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the animation after you add the `imageView` into the `view`. If you do the animation before the `addSubView` where at point, the image view is not in the view heirarchy and you can't see any animation.

```
 UIImageView * iv_tap = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gesture_tap"]];
[self.view addSubview:iv_tap];   //this could be self in your case
iv_tap.tag = 779; 

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.05  options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

    iv_tap.center=self.view.center;
    iv_tap.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.8, 1.8);

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];    //this could be self in your case

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //do your stuff when animation is done
}];
```

If you are subclassing a UIView, then you can even put this in the drawRect method:

```
UIImageView * iv_tap = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gesture_tap"]];
[self addSubview:iv_tap];   
iv_tap.tag = 779;

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.05  options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

    iv_tap.center=self.center;
    iv_tap.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.8, 1.8);

    [self layoutIfNeeded];   

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //do your stuff when animation is done
 }];
```

Comment: Actually that didn't do anything.

Comment: call layoutifneeded after the animation

Comment: I called [iv_tap layOUtIfNeeded] and it did not work either.

Comment: updated the answer @Firemarble. This is working for me

Comment: no,not the imageview, u need to update the self.viewq layoutifneeded

Comment: you can change the animation options according to your  need

Comment: My UIView was subclassed. Placing it in the DrawRect did work. But I use animations in other parts of the app and did not have to use the DrawRect method. Why do you think that would be? I have done no different initialization that I have with the other UIViews.